# How can I replace a sync ajax call with credentials to keep my app's state stable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I know that Firefox and jQuery don't allow sync requests with credentials. My problem is that I need to know if the user is logged in or not (by checking his session on the server by hitting an /echo endpoint).

Otherwise my Backbone application enters a bad state because when I navigate to a backbone route like #newActivity there is this logic in my controller:

```
         if (Session.status!=Session.LOGGED_IN) {
            Backbone.history.navigate('login', true);
            return;
        }
```

Session is a singleton object. In there if I hit async the /echo endpoint, until the time success is called my controller already thinks that we are not logged in.
Outcome: when the user refreshed the page he is always redirected in the login prompt.

If I make the request sync everything works ok with Chrome.

The request is:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: Config.serverUrl + "/rest/auth/echo",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
/*            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },*/
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                self.bootstrap(data)
                self.globalCh.vent.trigger('loggedIn',data.username);
            }
        });
```

I kind of understand why they want to phase out sync queries, but sometimes they are necessary for not having an unstable application state.

Any workarounds or ideas about a better implementation?

Comment: How are you hitting the */echo endpoint*..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use promises and/or deferred objects.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

jQuery's AJAX call returns a promise. That means you can fire a callback whereever you want to when the ajax call is finished.

add a `return` to your ajax request.

```
function getLoginInformation() {
    return $.ajax({
        // your ajax call to check if the user is logged in or not
    });
}
```

and then on page load, you fire the stuff that needs the login information AFTER you have it. Like this:

```
getLoginInformation().then(function(data) {
    // load the app and everything else that needs credentials
});
```

Comment: excellent solution. and when I want just to know if the user is logged in but without doing diffferent stuff I use the .always()